# How to generate coins and different obstacles in a 3D unity game using a c# sript?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 3D game in unity, i would like to know as to how I could generate coins and different obstacles randomly using a c# script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Instantiate Method](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/instantiate) along with [Random](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.html) Class to do this thing.
For Example:

```
 public class InstantiateExample : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject prefab;

        void Start()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(i * 2.0f, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
```

*In this example, we instantiate 10 copies of a prefab object in a line along the x axis.([More](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html))*
*

You can specify random position like this

```
    var position = Vector3(Random.Range(-10, 10), 0, Random.Range(-10, 10)); 
   Instantiate(prefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
```

while prefab is your object (like coin, obstacle, enemy etc).